# confusion on 2 dimension kernel density estimation in R

Tags: r, statistics, scikit-learn, kernel-density, probability-density

A kernel density estimator is used to estimate a particular probability density function (see [mvstat.net](http://www.mvstat.net/tduong/research/seminars/seminar-2001-05/) and [sckit-learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html) for references)

My confusion is about what exactly does `kde2d()` do? Does it estimate the joint distribution probability density function of two random variables *f(a,b)* in the below example? And what does the color mean?

Here is the code example I am referring to.

```
b <- log10(rgamma(1000, 6, 3))
a <- log10((rweibull(1000, 8, 2)))
density <- kde2d(a, b, n=100)

colour_flow <- colorRampPalette(c('white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'darkred'))
filled.contour(density, color.palette=colour_flow)
```

Comment: `Does it estimate the joint distribution probability density function of two random variables?` - yes. Since you have now three axes, `rv1`, `rv2` and `estimated probability`, you have to color-code one of them in order to be able to display them in a `2d` graph. So you can color-code the probability and/or draw contour lines of equal probabilty. See wikipedia for more details on contour lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line

Comment: Take a look at the source code for `kde2d`. It is often easy to disambiguate the 2d kde, once you know the 2d normal kernel density estimate is the product of two 1d normal kdes.

Comment: @cel, thanks and vote up, so **darkred** color means higher probability for `(x,y)` than **white**, correct? Does it also means in **darkred** area, random variable `x` and `y` has higher correlation than **white**?

Comment: @shayaa, thanks and vote up. So in  my code example, **darkred** color means higher probability for `(x,y)` than **white**, correct? Does it also means in **darkred** area, random variable `x` and `y` has higher correlation than **white**?

Answer (score 11):

**What is a kernel density estimator?**
Essentially it fits a little normal density curve over every point (the center of the normal density being that point) of the data and then adds up all little normal densities to a kernel density estimator.

For the sake of illustration I will add an image of a 1 dimensional kernel density estimator from [one of your links](http://www.mvstat.net/tduong/research/seminars/seminar-2001-05/).  [image]

**What about 2 dimensional kernel densities?**

```
# library(MASS)
b <- log10(rgamma(1000, 6, 3))
a <- log10((rweibull(1000, 8, 2)))
# a and b contain 1000 values each. 

density <- kde2d(a,b,n=100)
```

The function creates a grid from `min(a)` to `max(a)` and from `min(b)` to `max(b)`. Instead of fitting a tiny 1D normal density over every value in `a` or `b`, `kde2d` now fits a tiny 2D normal density over every point in the grid. Just like in the 1 dimensional case kernel density, it then adds up all density values.

**What do the colours mean?**
As @cel pointed out in the comments: the estimated probability depends on two variables, so we have three axes now (`a`, `b` and `estimated probability`). One way to visualize 3 axes is by using *iso-probability contours*. This sounds fancy, but it is basically the same as the high/low pressure images we know from the weather forecast.

You are using

```
filled.contour(density, 
    color.palette = colorRampPalette(c('white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'darkred')))))
```

So from low to high, the plot will be coloured `white`, `blue`, `yellow`, `red` and eventually `darkred` for the highest values of estimated probability. This results in the following plot: [image]

Comment: Thanks Ken, vote up. So in  my code example, **darkred** color means higher probability for `(x,y)` than **white**, correct? Does it also means in **darkred** area, random variable `x` and `y` has higher correlation than **white**?

Comment: @LinMa I edited the post. The colors do **not** represent correlation, they represent the value of the estimated joint density. Since `kde2d` does not incorporate a covariance matrix to model the relationship between `a` and `b`, I am sure it assumes independence of the values in `a` and `b`, i.e. `a` and `b` are uncorrelated.

Comment: Thanks Ken, vote up for the reply. I think for deeper color (darkred in your example), it means higher density -- which means `a` and `b` most likely occur in such darkred area, correct? If it is correct, why we cannot conclude `a` and `b` has higher correlation in the darkred area?

Comment: When variables are correlated with each other, it means that the outcome in `a` affects the outcome of `b`. In the case discussed in the question, the outcomes in `a` and `b` just happen to "intersect" often in the darkred area, simply because `a` happens to have many values in the `0.25` to `0.35` range and `b` has many values in the `0.3` to `0.4` range. Intuitively, you may say that knowing the value of `a` does not give you any additional information about the value of `b`.

Comment: Thanks Ken, vote up for your reply. From your comments -- "a happens to have many values in the 0.25 to 0.35 range and b has many values in the 0.3 to 0.4 range", does it mean the value change of `a` (from 0.25 to 0.35) impacts the value change of `b` (cluster into `0.3` to `0.4` area)? If I am wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: I meant the exact opposite ;) have a look at Wikipedia what independence means, or uncorrelatedness.

Comment: Thanks Ken, vote up for your reply. I know what means independence -- the behavior of one variable is random, independent of the change of another variable. My question is, what is wrong with my above conclusion for `a` and `b` has correlation? :)

Comment: I will explain with an example: Imagine there are two house parties, for which you record the age of the guests. The parties have nothing to do with each other, and therefore knowing the age of guest #5 on party A, does not provide any information on the age of guest #5 on party B (hence, the age-distributions are uncorrelated and independent). However, if we plotted the both age-distributions like the plot in my answer, we would likely have a dark-red area somewhere between 20 and 30 years." From this example we see that correlation and a dark-red area have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Ken The points in the grid are not normalize, right? Therefore the z value of the kde2d is more like a count. am I correct?. Thanks