# R: Understanding and Controlling "color shading" in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, heatmap

I am using the R programming language. I am following this tutorial this tutorial over here and I made the following plots: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-plot-with-ggplot2.html

```
#load library
library(ggplot2)

#create data
a <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20000, 10, 1.9), y=rnorm(20000, 10, 1.2) )
b <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20000, 14.5, 1.9), y=rnorm(20000, 14.5, 1.9) )
c <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20000, 9.5, 1.9), y=rnorm(20000, 15.5, 1.9) )
data <- rbind(a,b,c)


# plot 1
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette=4, direction=-1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
 
# plot 2
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette=4, direction=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
 
# plot 3
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette= "Spectral", direction=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
```

[image]

Can anyone please walk me through the process as to how a 2 dimensional coordinate (data$a, data$b) is converted into a continuous and shaded color plot? Is a 2 dimensional coordinate converted into 3 coordinates (e.g. Red, Blue, Green or Hue, Lum, Saturation?) using some mapping function? How do certain regions on this map (that do not have an exact coordinate in the dataset) have their colors "interpolated"?

Are there any videos, documentation, website, blogs etc. that explain the math behind this process?

Thanks

Comment: There is a good description of how this is done in one-dimension in Wikipedia [Kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).  If you understand that, you will have a good idea of how it can  be done in higher dimensions.

Comment: Closely related if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769294/6851825

Comment: @G5W : I looked for the formula for kernel density estimation in one dimension. This seems understandable. Suppose you have measurements for a single variable "x" and you are trying to estimate a probability density function for the variable x.  If you assume a kernel (K) and bandwidth (h), the estimate of the density of x at any given point: 1/n*h (sum(K(x - xi/h)) . Now, I am trying to understand how this would work for 2 dimensions. Does the above formula still apply for 2 dimensions? Thank you for all your help. (note: this "formula" is from the wikipedia page you linked to)

Comment: Yes,  that formula applies as long as you take x to be a two dimensional vector and K to be a function of a two-dimensional variable.

Comment: thank you for all your help! is there any chance you can take a look at this question if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66512544/r-pandoc-error-251-when-saving-leaflet-maps